# epoll_wait with timerfd api for non blocking reads

Tags: c, linux, timer, posix, epoll

I am trying to integrate epoll_wait with timerfd API. I need non blocking timerfd reads and blocking epoll_wait that should be triggered when timerfd file descriptor is ready to read.

I set epoll_wait event flags as EPOLLIN and call timerfd create function with TFD_NONBLOCK flag. In this case I got timer messages successfully. But my problem : epoll_wait is triggered continuously since always got EPOLLIN events. Even though EPOLLIN events received ; non blocking read for timer fd returns EAGAIN until next timerfd expiration.

I am confused why EPOLLIN continuously returned from epoll_wait in spite of timer fd does not got a value yet  and its read call returns EAGAIN?

Second step I tried to set epoll_wait events as (EPOLLIN | EPOLLET). This time timer fd read called once with first EPOLLIN and epoll_wait blocked forever.

Is there a wrong assumption for using timer fd with epoll_wait ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timerfd with epoll_wait() call.
Make sure that the timeout is specified as -1 to make it a blocking call.
eg: epoll_wait(epfd, evlist, MAX_EVENTS, -1);